# Replacing values of a list with values of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, zip

I have a list and a dictionary. I am trying to replace the values of the list in the dictionary with the values from the dictionary. I am trying to replace that are keys in the dictionary and keep the rest of the values as it is in the list.
Here is the code I have -

```
list_1 = [[['bg_en', 'AB2_XY_EN', 'AB2'], ['AB2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'CD2_XY_EN'], ['CD2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'AB3_XY_EN'], ['AB3_MAN']]]
dict_1 = {'AB2_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], 'CD2_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], 'AB3_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL']}

new_list_1 = []
for i in list_1:
    sm_list_2 = []
    for j in i:
        sm_list_3 = []
        for k in j:
            for x, y in dict_1.items():
                if k == x:
                    sm_list_3.append(y)
                else:
                    sm_list_3.append(k)
        sm_list_2.append(sm_list_3)
    new_list_1.append(sm_list_2)
print(new_list_1)
```

I am not getting the desired output.
The output I am looking got is of sort -

```
[[['bg_en', 'XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL', 'AB2'], ['AB2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], ['CD2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], ['AB3_MAN']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

your program needs a small change

```
list_1 = [[['bg_en', 'AB2_XY_EN', 'AB2'], ['AB2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'CD2_XY_EN'], ['CD2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'AB3_XY_EN'], ['AB3_MAN']]]
dict_1 = {'AB2_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], 'CD2_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], 'AB3_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL']}

new_list_1 = []
for i in list_1:
    sm_list_2 = []
    for j in i:
        sm_list_3 = []
        for k in j:
            # if the item is in dict, append the values from the dict, else just apend the item
            sm_list_3 += dict_1.get(k, [k])
        sm_list_2.append(sm_list_3)
    new_list_1.append(sm_list_2)
print(new_list_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think recursion is a better solution

```
list_1 = [[['bg_en', 'AB2_XY_EN', 'AB2'], ['AB2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'CD2_XY_EN'], ['CD2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'AB3_XY_EN'], ['AB3_MAN']]]
dict_1 = {'AB2_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], 'CD2_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], 'AB3_XY_EN': ['XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL']}


def replace(list_):
    temp = []
    for i in list_:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            temp.append(replace(i))
        elif v := dict_1.get(i):
            temp.extend(v)
        else:
            temp.append(i)
    return temp

print(replace(list_1))
```

Output

```
[[['bg_en', 'XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL', 'AB2'], ['AB2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], ['CD2_MAN']], [['bg_en', 'XY_EN ', 'XY_SEL'], ['AB3_MAN']]]
```